# Create a table listing records that don't match when inner joining to tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, inner-join, create-table

Example of what I am seeking:

In table:

ua-485
gh-684
hk-238
lh-568
lf-586
gf-271

In DB

ua-485
lh-568
lf-586
gf-271

The table contains gh-684, hk-238, but the DB doesn't, I would a query that puts the records that are in the table but don't match any in the DB into a table.

Hi so I am trying to update the tonnage information in our database using the query below, but when going to run it I see that the amount of records that would be updated in the database isn't the amount in the table. So this must mean that the records names are not the same, is it possible to a make a query that will compare the two then, create a table that shows all the records in the table that don't match that of the database I am trying to upload to, so that I can correct the names without having to go through every record?

Database=Raw material reg info

Table=2013 yearly region inventory info

Thanks,

```
UPDATE 

    [Raw material reg info]

INNER JOIN 

[2013 yearly region inventory info] ON [Raw material reg info].[Supplier name/Trade name] = [2013 yearly region inventory info].[RM names] 

SET 

[Raw material reg info].[US 2013] = [2013 yearly region inventory info].[NA],
[Raw material reg info].[LatAm KG's 2013 - Mexico] = [2013 yearly region inventory info].[MX],
[Raw material reg info].[China KG's 2013] = [2013 yearly region inventory info].[JS],
[Raw material reg info].[EU KG's 2013] = [2013 yearly region inventory info].[EU],
[Raw material reg info].[LatAm KG's 2013 - Brazil] = [2013 yearly region inventory info].[BR];
```

Comment: This lists everything in the database that doesn't appear in the table, I wanted it to only list the records from the table that aren't the same as those in the database, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To get the names that don't match, you can use `left join` like this:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM [Raw material reg info] as r LEFT JOIN
     [2013 yearly region inventory info] as ri
     ON r.[Supplier name/Trade name] = ri.[RM names]
WHERE ri.[RM names] IS NULL;
```

Comment: what are the "r"'s for in this statement?

Comment: @user3930153 . . . They are table aliases.  They just make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: This lists everything in the database that doesn't appear in the table, I wanted it to only list the records from the table that aren't the same as those in the database, is this possible?

Comment: @user3930153 . . . I am not clear on what you want.  Perhaps you should swap the tables in the `left join` and that might do what you want.

Comment: I have edited the question with an example of what I want the query to do, this may help.

Answer (score 0):

This will show you all the records in the main table that are not in the joined tabled.

```
SELECT * FROM
[Raw material reg info] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [2013 yearly region inventory info] ON [Raw material reg info].[Supplier name/Trade name] = [2013 yearly region inventory info].[RM names]
WHERE [2013 yearly region inventory info].[RM names] IS NULL
```

To check the other way, make it a RIGHT OUTER JOIN and check for null on the first table.

Comment: This lists everything in the database that doesn't appear in the table, I wanted it to only list the records from the table that aren't the same as those in the database, is this possible?